# Parse includeKey returns nil value

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Chats")
                query.whereKey("event", equalTo: event!)
                query.includeKey("sender")
                query.includeKey("event")
                query.includeKey("likes")

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ...
```

My code goes like this. Once i get all the chat objects from parse when I try to access

```
    var pfHost = aChat.valueForKey("sender") as! PFUser
```

It throws an exception saying valueForKey("sender") is nil. I confirmed in parse and I can see the pointer in DB. So its not actually nil, but in response it comes as nil.

So I checked if the event pointer is also nil, as its the same kind of relation, but its not.

```
var pfHost = aChat.valueForKey("event") as! PFObject
```

Have anyone came across anything like this? Found any clues why this is happening?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try removing the `includeKey` lines?

Comment: No I didnt try that! Since they are pointers, my understanding was i should use includeKey.

Comment: Oh, I see. Try replacing `valueForKey` with `objectForKey` and it should work.

Comment: Weird, I removed include key and now i got the PFUser object !!

Comment: Now let me try objectForKey thing

Comment: Can you simply try `aChat["sender"]`

Comment: I tried po aChat.description and i can see there is no sender object in it.